# What is the difference between $o(x)$ and $o(x^{2})$?

Tags: calculus, limits, notation

I think both $f(x) = o(x)$ and $g(x) = o(x^{2})$ tell $\lim_ {x\rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 0 $ and $\lim_ {x\rightarrow \infty} g(x) = 0 $

So, how does the degree of inner x in the little o notation matter?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation

Comment: See [little-o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation).

Comment: @mauroALLEGRANZA Thank you, so $f(x) = o(x)$ means the function $f(x)$ grows slower than the function $t(x) = x$ That makes sense, and does that also implies the rate of $f(x)$ goes to 0 is faster than $t(x)$?